# Enqueue Text Area

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to get my queue -- what the user types in the textfield, gets added to the textarea by using enqueue and when they click the dequeue button, the queue gets removed.  I have everything already programmed, but I cannot seem to get it to work with the gui...

panel class:

```
public QueuePanel() {

    enqueueButton = new JButton(enqueueButtonText);
    dequeueButton = new JButton(dequeueButtonText);

    contentsTextArea = new JTextArea(20,30);
    enqueueTextField = new JTextField("Type here", 15);


    add(enqueueButton);
    add(dequeueButton);
    add(contentsTextArea);
    add(enqueueTextField);

    enqueueButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

}
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        OurQueue theQueue = new OurQueue();
        if(enqueueButton.isSelected()){
            theQueue.first();


        }

    }
}
```

}
My Main:

```
public class QueueGui {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Queue Gui");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        QueuePanel panel = new QueuePanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 396));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Node:

```
 public class Node {

 private Object data;
 private Node next;

    public Node(){
        data = null;
        next = null;
    }

    public Node(Object o){
        data = o;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Queue Class:

```
 public class OurQueue {

 private Node front;
 private Node back;

    public OurQueue(){
        front = null;
        back = null;
    }

    public void enqueue(Object o){
        Node newNode = new Node(o);
        if (front == null){
            back = newNode;
            front = newNode;
        }else{ // if queue is NOT empty
            back.setNext(newNode);
            back = newNode;
        }
    }

    public Object dequeue(){
        Object o = front.getData();
        front = front.getNext();
        return o;
    }

    public Object first(){
        return front.getData();
    }

    public boolean empty(){
        return (front == null);
    }
}
```

So like I said, everything is done, I'm just trying to get the actual gui to work with the gui. I'm not exactly sure what to do to be honest.  How does a person go about getting the button to actually add to the queue, take from the queue and then display the result in the Text area?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> How does a person go about getting the button to actually add to the queue, take from the queue and then display the result in the Text area?

In your ActionListener the basic code would be:

```
textArea.append("some text here");
```

Although I'm really not sure what your Nodes represent. They don't appear to be textual components. Also, since you have a requirement to remove text it may be easier to use a JList, since each item you add to the JList would represent a node so it would be easier to remove the last item from the JList.

Comment: The nodes are to add to or take away from.  I used it to create a data type, too...